# Line not appearing after the table

Tags: tables, floats

so I don't know why the "N/A indicates that there $\nexists$ any $\mu$ that the model becomes infeasible" appears towards the start of the table when should appear towards the end.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Parameter estimates for 2018 DTaP case study}
\centering 
\begin{tabular} {c c c }
\hline
Model component & Base Value & Sensitivity Analysis\\
\hline
$D$ & 4.034M & [4.0M, 7.832M] \\
$\mu$ & $10^{-4}$  & N/A \\
$\gamma$ & 0.25 & [0,0.5] \\
$K_{inf}. K_{Dap}$ & 4.034M & [2.837M, 4.034M] \\
$P_{inf}, P_{Dap}$ & \$ 39.8M, \$45.1M & [\$26.5, \$ 53.0M]  \\
$\rho_{inf}, \rho_{Dap}$ & \$ 18.62, \$18.02 & N/A \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

N/A indicates that there $\nexists$ any $\mu$ that the model becomes infeasible.
```

Comment: What is the problem? Table compile fine ... How your question is related to LaTeX?

Comment: the line does not appear after the table.. it appears before the table. And that's a LaTeX question.

Comment: you have not provided code that we can run, it shows three `\hline` in the table one at the top one after the first row and one at the end. Which do you not see in the output?

Comment: You need add placement specification to your `table`, for example `\begin{table}[ht]`

Comment: @Zarko ah! thanks, I think you are correct: the OP meant line of text not a line as in a \rule ...

Comment: The `table` environment is meant to float -- it probably won't stay where you input it.  If you want it to appear in a particular place (and it fits on the page) you can simply use a `tabular` environment.  If you put that between `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` it will have some vertical space around it and be centered horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sentence

```
N/A indicates that there $\nexists$ any $\mu$ that the model becomes infeasible.
```

appears to provide a legend to some of the tabular material, you should make it part of the `table` environment itself, placing it below the `tabular` environment but before `\end{table}`. That way, the legend will never become separated from the material it is meant to illustrate.

There are many ways of doing so. One way is to employ the machinery of the `threeparttable` package. An advantage of this approach is that the width of the material *below* the `tabular` environment (here, the legend) will be line-broken as needed so as not exceed the width of the `tabular` environment. (This also applies to the caption, by the way.)

For good measure, and in order to give the table a more open "look", I would also load the `booktabs` package and use its line-drawing macros -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule` -- instead of the basic `\hline` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % unless you have a very good reason to use OT1
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for '\nexists' macro
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering 
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Parameter estimates for 2018 DTaP case study}
\begin{tabular} {@{} c c c @{}}
\toprule %\hline
Model component & Base Value & Sensitivity Analysis\\
\midrule % \hline
$D$ & 4.034M & [4.0M, 7.832M] \\
$\mu$ & $10^{-4}$ & N/A \\
$\gamma$ & 0.25 & [0, 0.5] \\ \addlinespace % provide some visual grouping
$K_{\inf}$, $K_{\mathrm{Dap}}$ & 4.034M & [2.837M, 4.034M] \\
$P_{\inf}$, $P_{\mathrm{Dap}}$ & \$39.8M, \$45.1M & [\$26.5, \$53.0M] \\
$\rho_{\inf}$, $\rho_{\mathrm{Dap}}$ & \$18.62, \$18.02 & N/A \\
\bottomrule %\hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip\footnotesize
N/A indicates that there $\nexists$ any $\mu$ that the model becomes infeasible.
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Always amazing how much effort you put into your answers.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Many thanks for your very kind compliment!